# Can not connect to Postgres database instance on Google cloud

Tags: postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, gcloud

I'm having trouble connect to the database on google cloud.
In my Dockerfile, I'm calling a python script to connect to the database, as follows:

#### Dockerfile:

```
....
ADD script.py /home/script.py
CMD ["/home/script.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

#### Python script

```
import sqlalchemy as db
# x.x.x.x is the public ip of the database instance
engine = db.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:db_pass@x.x.x.x/db_name')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()
experiments = db.Table('experiments', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Operation timed out
          Is the server running on host "x.x.x.x" and accepting
          TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!!

Comment: I connected to the database by using unix socket. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#python We also need to enable the connection on cloud sql instance. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run